# Understand math | notation within a problem

Tags: notation, relations

The question:

Let R be a relation over the positive integers defined as follows:

$ \{ (a,b) \mid $ gcd$(a,b) > 1  $ but $ a \nmid b  $ and $b \nmid a \} $

Determine whether or not R satisfies the following properties. reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, and transitive. Give a brief justification for each of your answers.

My attempt at figuring out what the relation statement meant:

$(a,b)$ exists such that the greatest common divisor of $(a,b)$ is greater than 1. But, a doesn't divide into b and b doesn't divide into a.

Comment: What‘s the question?

Comment: That's a correct interpretation yes.

Comment: $R$ is a relation defined as the set of all ordered pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $a,b$ satisfy the property that the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is greater than $1$ while also satisfying the property that $a$ is not a multiple of $b$ as well as $b$ is not a multiple of $a$.

Comment: @LukasKofler I posted the question, but I haven't given it a shot as I wasn't sure if my interpretation of the relation statement was correct.

Comment: Examples of pairs in the relation would be things such as $(6,9)$, $(15,10)$ and $(20,15)$ etc... while examples of pairs *not* in the relation would be things such as $(1,5)$, $(2,7)$, $(5,5)$ and $(10,20)$

Comment: You can interpret your relation as saying that $a$ and $b$ have at least one prime factor but not all prime factors in common.

Comment: @LukasKofler  Consider $(4,12)$.

Comment: @EthanBolker then $4 | 12$.

Answer (score 2):

Almost. I wouldn't say "$(a,b)$ exists".

This relation is the set of pairs with gcd greater than $1$ where neither divides the other. So it contains $(6,15)$ but not $(6,18)$ and of course not $(6,7)$. (Writing down a few examples is always a good way to test your understanding.)

Comment: I would then say R is NOT reflexive as $(a,a) \notin R$ for all $a \in A$. If $(a,a)$ existed it would divide itself.

Comment: You're right - it's not reflexive.

Comment: Would it make sense to say that the relation is:

Not anti-symmetric as as $(a,b) \wedge (b,a) \exists \in R$

I have only seen the $\exists$ symbol in front of the pairs before. Usually with a $\forall$